# How to plot candle with offset in Tradingview?

Tags: plot, pine-script, tradingview-api

i have a little question for you guys. I want to plot last candle from that serie in offset but i don t know how or if it s possible!  ( i attached my pinescript)

Thx you in advance for any help

```
//@version=3
study("CandlesMath", overlay=true)

//Calculation
lb = input(2,title = "Lookback")
hc = highest(high,lb + 1)
oc = open[lb]
cc = close
lc = lowest(low,lb + 1)

//plot
plotcandle(oc, hc, lc, cc, color = oc < cc ? blue : orange , wickcolor = black, bordercolor =       black,  show_last = 1)
```

`Thx you`

//[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLLsf.png)